# Filtering columns from large file based on a column list

Tags: r, bash

I have list of samples as a txt file and want to only keep these samples from this large file; column name is samples name in the large file.

```r
library(readr)
library(data.table)

df1 <- read_csv("control.csv", col_types = cols(Chromosome = col_skip(), Start = col_skip(), End = col_skip(), Strand = col_skip()))

df1[1:5,1:5]
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  ID          DN54 DC146 DDN44 DC179
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 cg26928153 0.848 0.879 0.872 0.897
2 cg16269199 0.731 0.732 0.759 0.775
3 cg13869341 0.842 0.863 0.819 0.896
4 cg24669183 0.824 0.866 0.822 0.910
5 cg26679879 0.425 0.363 0.420 0.358
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is a straightforward R operation.

Comment: it is resolved now, I have updated my code above.

Comment: "I have updated my code above" - Don't do that, add an answer and accept it instead.

Comment: Thanks Ram, I will add correct code as answer soon.

Answer (score 3):

You can save time and memory by preprocessing your file before loading it into R.

Use [`miller`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/) toolkit to manipulate csv or tab-delimited files using column names.

Below is a one-liner that reads csv file, and writes columns specified in option `-f`, in the order (`-o`) listed on the command line:

```
mlr --csv cut -o -f col3,col1 in.csv > out.csv
```

To read the list of columns from a file, 1 column name per line:

```
mlr --csv cut -o -f $(paste -s -d, columns.txt) in.csv > out.csv
```

**See also:**

Note that [`miller`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) can be easily installed, for example, using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html), specifically `miniconda`, like so:

```
conda create --channel conda-forge --name miller miller
```

Answer (score 3):

It's really just `count[,col$V1]`. Please learn about basic subsetting of columns and rows, it's simple yet powerful.

Comment: thanks but it is not giving me CpG ID in first column.

Comment: There you see that you're not investing time into understanding an answer. What this here does is to provide names to the object to be filtered using the inbuilt R filtering operator. If you need the names plus something else then add this. Like `c(cpg_name, col$V1)`. Show some effort.

Comment: Thanks @ATpoint, it is sorted now and with your command, I was also not getting column names.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works perfectly of me.

```r
library(readr)
library(data.table)

df1 <- read_csv("control.csv", col_types = cols(Chromosome = col_skip(), Start = col_skip(), End = col_skip(), Strand = col_skip()))

df1[1:5,1:5]
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  ID          DN54 DC146 DDN44 DC179
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 cg26928153 0.848 0.879 0.872 0.897
2 cg16269199 0.731 0.732 0.759 0.775
3 cg13869341 0.842 0.863 0.819 0.896
4 cg24669183 0.824 0.866 0.822 0.910
5 cg26679879 0.425 0.363 0.420 0.358

col <- unlist(fread("samples.csv", header=F))
col <- c("ID", col)
extracted <- df1[,col, with=F]

write.table(extracted, file="control.beta.txt",sep=",", quote=F, col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE)

df <- read_csv("control.beta.txt")
df[1:5,1:5]
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  ID         DC103R DC110R DC115 DC120R
  <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 cg26928153  0.929  0.885 0.862  0.877
2 cg16269199  0.836  0.826 0.604  0.739
3 cg13869341  0.826  0.903 0.830  0.841
4 cg24669183  0.767  0.719 0.808  0.812
5 cg26679879  0.388  0.366 0.428  0.360
```